# Isolating values from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lets say I have a string "255, 100, 0".
How do I isolate each value before the comma and inserting it into a var?

I mean:

`x = 255;
y = 100;
z = 0;`

Comment: A capturing regex will do the trick.  Someone will probably post one here before I can come up with it ;)

Comment: @asymptoticFault: Funny, `.split()` seemed easier than `/^(\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)$/`, however, I would use a regex either, prevents me from accidentally splitting invalid strings.

Comment: Do you want string values or numerical ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = "255, 100, 0";
var str_new = str.split(",");

var x = str_new[0];
var y = str_new[1];
var z = str_new[2];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "255, 100, 0";
var d = str.split(",");

var x = parseInt(d[0],10); // always use a radix
var y = parseInt(d[1],10);
var z = parseInt(d[2],10);

console.log(x); //255
console.log(y); //100
console.log(z); //0
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the under-appreciated [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method will return an array of all matches, in the order they are found:

```
var str = "255, 100, 0",
    regex = /(\d+)/g,    // g is for "global" -- returns multiple matches
    arr = str.match(regex);
console.log(arr);        // ["255","100","0"] -- an array of strings, not numbers
```

To convert them into numbers, use a simple loop:

```
for (var i=0,j=arr.length; i<j; i++) {
    arr[i] *= 1;
};                     // arr = [255, 100, 0] -- an array of numbers, not strings
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = "255, 100, 0";
var arrNums = string.split(",");
```

Will put each of the numbers into an element of the `arrNums` array.

Answer (score 0):

Have look at the Javascript split method 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

```
var str = "255, 100, 0";
var array = str.split(',');
```

Then you can loop through the array and create your variables, or better use the array directly

Answer (score 0):

try using the JavaScript split() Method

```
var str = "255, 100, 0";
var elements = str.split(','); //take values to an array
//access the elements with array index
var x = elements[0];
var y = elements[1];
var z = elements[2];
```

[w3schools documentation here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Comment: Never link to w3schools if you can link to [real documentation instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) -- they've been known to get the details wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you got the following string:

```
var string = "x = 255; y = 100; z = 0;";
```

You should indeed play with `split` function:

```
var values = [];
var expressions = string.split("; ");
for (var i = 0, c = expressions.length ; i < c ; i++) {
    values.push(expressions[i].split("= ").pop() * 1);
}
```

In `expressions`, you will get values like `x = 255`. Then, you just have to cut to the `=`. I just multiply it by 1 to cast it into a int.

Comment: Reread the question carefully. You're using his output string as your input string.

Answer (score 0):

If you string is indeed well known/formed:

```
var str = "255, 100, 0";
var vals = str.split(', '); // <<= you can split on multiple chars

var x = +vals[0]; // <<= coerces to a number

// lather, rinse, repeat
```